# Number of unread messages in system tray kmail icon

Tags: kubuntu, kde, icons, system-tray, kmail

In previous versions of KDE, the system tray icon of KMail showed the number of unread messages on the mail icon. For instance, in Kubuntu 14.04 I had the following:
[image: Old mail icon showing unread messages]

In recent versions of KDE the number disappeared, and has been substituted by a very small asterisk. For instance, in Kubuntu 22.04 I have the following:

[image]

How can I show again the number of unread messages in the KMail icon?